# ExpressJS - function returning undefinded

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, mongoose, async-await

function `checkFamilyStatus()` keeps returning undefined for some reason, when it should be returning a boolean value from a mongodb collection.

A bit of context here - I decided to separate the logic part from the router methods like get and post methods, so as to make it look clean and understandable like in functional programming. So I put the logic part in functions and invoke them inside the router methods, but it doesn't work out. Besides, I don't know if this is a good practice or not. Wouldn't it be much easier to read if done like this, instead of say, putting a whole bunch of code in one place?

I've been stuck on this piece of code for a while. I am a bit confused on the working of asynchronous JS as a whole. I did some research, but still don't understand why this wouldn't work. Could someone clarify this up for me?

```js
// post method 
router.post("/create", ensureAuthenticated, async(req, res) => {
      let userID = req.user.id;
      console.log(await checkFamilyStatus(userID)); // but returns undefined
      // rest of the code
    }



    // check family status
    checkFamilyStatus = async userID => {
      Account.findOne({
        _id: userID
      }, (err, account) => {
        return account.hasFamily; // should return boolean value ?
      });
    };
```

Comment: Shouldn't the post method wait till the completion of checkFamilyStatus() ? 
Till it returns the promise?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the logic behind `account.hasFamily` is correct, then you need to `await` for the return, so it should be `return await account.hasFamily;`

Comment: Yes, inside the checkFamilyStatus() , the value of account.hasFamily is being queried properly, as I tried console logging its value inside the function checkFamilyStatus(). But its not returning it to the post method.

Comment: I tried doing what you said, but it's the same as before. still returning undefined. 

Besides, why would I need to add await keyword with the return statement ?
Could you please clarify that ? From what I know, 'account' is being passed as callback to the Mongoose findOne() function, so I don't need to await for the value, right?